# What is not working to show Shiny App's dropdown menu

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a shiny web app that shows a simple visualization based on a company's stock information. Data gets fetched via Alpha Stock API. I want end users to use dropdown menu based on their input, functioning like a search box, to select which company's visualization they want to see. For instance, their input is "APP", then I want to create the dropdown menu that shows company's symbols containing "APP" such APPL and other companies.

With this in mind, I started writing code, but some issues appeared. How can I do to make this work?

```
# loading libraries

library(httr2)
library(jsonlite)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(repurrrsive)
library(shinythemes)
library(DescTools)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  navbarPage(
    title = "Stock Analysis",
    tabPanel(title = "Stock Visualization",
             sidebarPanel(
               textInput(inputId = "search_stock",
                         label = "search stock symbol",
                         value = ""),
               actionButton(inputId = "searchButton",
                            label = "Search"),
               selectInput(inputId = "symbol_input",
                           label = "Select Symbol",
                           choices = NULL),
               selectInput(inputId = "metrics", 
                           label = "Select a metric",
                           choices = c("open",
                                       "high",
                                       "low",
                                       "close",
                                       "volume")),
               radioButtons(inputId = "movementType", 
                            label = "Select Movement Type:",
                            choices = c("Daily" = "DAILY", "Monthly" = "MONTHLY")),
               actionButton(inputId = "exe", 
                            label = "Create a plot")),
             mainPanel(
               plotOutput(outputId = "plot1"),
               )),
             ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$searchButton, {
    
    # Perform the API request and update result_new based on the user's input
    stock_tickers_input <- input$search_stock  # Use appropriate input field here
    test_results <- get_test_results(stock_tickers_input)
    
    # Extract stock symbols and update result_new
    stock_symbol_tib <- tibble(stock_symbol = resp_body_json(resp = test_results))
    
    # Call the function by passing the 'stock_symbol_tib' argument
    result <- extract_stock_symbols(stock_symbol_tib = stock_symbol_tib)
    result_new <- print(result[1:length(stock_symbol_tib$stock_symbol$bestMatches)])
    result_new <- unlist(result_new, recursive = FALSE)
    
    updateSelectInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "symbol_input",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = result_new)
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$exe, {
    
    
    fetched_df <- fetch_stock_data(movementType = input$movementType,
                                   symbol_input = input$symbol_input,
                                   metrics = input$metrics)
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      
     fetched_plot <- ggplot(data = fetched_df, 
             mapping = aes(x = "date", y = input$symbol_input)) +
        geom_line() +
        labs(x = "Date",
             y = "Price") +
        theme_minimal()
    })
    
    updateSelectInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "metrics",
                      label = NULL,
                      choices = c("open",
                                  "high",
                                  "low",
                                  "close",
                                  "volume"))
    
  })
  
  # Function to get test results from the API
  get_test_results <- function(stock_tickers_input) {
    
        # user input - users can select tickers and analysis type
        api_key <- "Y5WETUTTY7DR3OQ7"
        analysis_type <- "SYMBOL_SEARCH"
        stock_tickers <- stock_tickers_input

        # this base url is static
        baseurl <- request("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?")

        # feeding input into this code chunk
        test_url <- baseurl %>%
          req_url_query(`function` = analysis_type,
                        keywords = stock_tickers,
                        apikey = api_key)

        # 200 status check: can be used to validate user input?
        test_results <- req_perform(test_url)

    return(test_results)
  }
  
  # Function to extract stock symbols from API response
  extract_stock_symbols <- function(stock_symbol_tib) {
    

  # Initialize an empty list to store stock symbols
        stock_symbols <- vector("list", length = length(stock_symbol_tib$stock_symbol$bestMatches))

        # Loop through each company and extract the stock symbol
        for (i in seq_along(stock_symbol_tib$stock_symbol$bestMatches)) {
          stock_symbols[[i]] <- stock_symbol_tib$stock_symbol$bestMatches[[i]][['1. symbol']]
        }
    return(stock_symbols)
  }
  
  fetch_stock_data <-  function(movementType,
                                symbol_input,
                                metrics) {
    function_type <- ifelse(movementType == "DAILY", 
                            "TIME_SERIES_DAILY", 
                            "TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY")
    
    baseurl <- request("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?")
    fetch_url <- baseurl %>%
      req_url_query(`function` = function_type,
                    symbol = symbol_input,
                    apikey = "Y5WETUTTY7DR3OQ7")
    
    fetch_results <- req_perform(fetch_url)
    
    stock <- tibble(stock_results = resp_body_json(resp = fetch_results)[[2]])
    
    stock_df <- unnest_wider(stock,
                             "stock_results")
    
    stock_df$date <- names(stock$stock_results)
    
    colnames(stock_df) <- c("open","high","low","close","volume","date")
    
    stock_df <- stock_df %>%
      mutate(open = as.numeric(open),
             high = as.numeric(high),
             low = as.numeric(low),
             close = as.numeric(close),
             volume = as.numeric(volume),
             date = as.Date(date))
    
    stock_df <- stock_df %>% 
      select(metrics,"date")
    
    return(stock_df)
  }
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Drop the line `stock_tickers_input <- input$symbol_input` from your function `get_test_results`. It is not needed. Also, you should never ever post a personal API key or any private credentials as part of your post.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Then when and where will the symbol_input be used ??

Comment: Hi Ryo. Well, as far as I understand the logic of your app, the user submits his search and the select input gets populated by stocks matching the search term. In a second step he chooses the symbol he wants to be visualized. Hence, you need a second observeEvent and probably a second button to retrieve the data for the chosen symbol.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I now have this code. Getting close to the super basic, but functionable point, however, my code doesn't produce a plot. Do you see any errors here?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code. First, to retrieve the data from the API I would suggest to use an `eventReactive` which I called `fetched_df` to store the data. Second, move the `output$plot1` outside of the `observeEvent` or `eventReactive`. There you can use `fetched_df()` to access the downloaded data. Also, in the ggplot code use unquoted column names, i.e. `date` instead of `"date"`. Moreover, the name of second column to be mapped on `y` is the name of the metric. Using the so-called `.data` pronoun we can map this column only `y` using `.data[[input$metrics]]`. Finally, I dropped the `updateSelectInput` for the metrics which IMO is not needed.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ...

  # Replace observeEvent(input$exe, { ... }) with following code blocks
 
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(fetched_df())
    
    ggplot(
      data = fetched_df(),
      mapping = aes(x = date, y = .data[[input$metrics]])
    ) +
      geom_line() +
      labs(
        x = "Date",
        y = "Price"
      ) +
      theme_minimal()
  })
  
  fetched_df <- eventReactive(input$exe, {
    fetch_stock_data(
      movementType = input$movementType,
      symbol_input = input$symbol_input,
      metrics = input$metrics
    )
  })

  ...

}
```

[image]

Comment: _Thank you very much!_